# Error runing mftf in Magento 2.3.5 I get an error on build:project

Tags: magento2, functional-testing

First time eveer runing mftf I installed with composer with in a m2 2.3.5 and when I run the build I get this message:

```
mftf build:project

mftf files removed from filesystem.
codeception.yml applied to /var/www/html/dev/tests/acceptance/codeception.yml
functional.suite.yml configuration successfully applied.
functional.suite.yml applied to /var/www/html/dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional.suite.yml
command.php copied to /var/www/html/dev/tests/acceptance/utils/command.php
.credentials.example successfully applied.
.env configuration successfully applied.

In Configuration.php line 212:
                                                     
  Output path is not defined by key "paths: output"  
                                                     

In BuildProjectCommand.php line 105:
                                                                                                 
  The codecept build command failed unexpectedly. Please see the above output for more details.
```

Any ideas what can be ?